# How can I export JSON which looks like Neo4j Browser export button?

Tags: python, json, neo4j, export, py2neo

I would like to reproduce the Neo4j Browser JSON format which is something like this :

```
[
{
    "p": {
        "start": {
            "identity": 2,
            "labels": [
                "Person"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "born": 1964,
                "name": "Keanu Reeves"
            }
        },
        "end": {
            "identity": 155,
            "labels": [
                "Movie"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "title": "Something's Gotta Give",
                "released": 2003
            }
        },
        "segments": [
            {
                "start": {
                    "identity": 2,
                    "labels": [
                        "Person"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "born": 1964,
                        "name": "Keanu Reeves"
                    }
                },
                "relationship": {
                    "identity": 221,
                    "start": 2,
                    "end": 155,
                    "type": "ACTED_IN",
                    "properties": {
                        "roles": [
                            "Julian Mercer"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "end": {
                    "identity": 155,
                    "labels": [
                        "Movie"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "title": "Something's Gotta Give",
                        "released": 2003
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "length": 1
    }
},
{
    "p": {
        "start": {
            "identity": 2,
            "labels": [
                "Person"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "born": 1964,
                "name": "Keanu Reeves"
            }
        },
        "end": {
            "identity": 88,
            "labels": [
                "Movie"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "tagline": "Pain heals, Chicks dig scars... Glory lasts forever",
                "title": "The Replacements",
                "released": 2000
            }
        },
        "segments": [
            {
                "start": {
                    "identity": 2,
                    "labels": [
                        "Person"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "born": 1964,
                        "name": "Keanu Reeves"
                    }
                },
                "relationship": {
                    "identity": 114,
                    "start": 2,
                    "end": 88,
                    "type": "ACTED_IN",
                    "properties": {
                        "roles": [
                            "Shane Falco"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "end": {
                    "identity": 88,
                    "labels": [
                        "Movie"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "tagline": "Pain heals, Chicks dig scars... Glory lasts forever",
                        "title": "The Replacements",
                        "released": 2000
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "length": 1
    }
  }
]
```

I've tried to do it with an httpie command to in order to retrieve what is sent to the transactional cypher endpoint but I got something with data, rows and metadata.

My goal is to retrieve a part of my database with a Cypher request, and to retrieve via Python, the JSON like the one of the Neo4j Browser button.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve via Python, and keep it as dict type, then you can use json to save this dict with parameter "indent".

```
import json
my_dict = {'name': ['Raphael', 'Donatello'],
            'mask': ['red', 'purple'],
            'weapon': ['sai', 'bo staff']}
with open('/Users/peter/temp/test.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(my_dict, f, indent=2)
```

[json.dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage)